# My PC has a black screen and the CPU power switch light is flashing

Tags: windows, sleep

I kept my computer on but in sleep mode and went somewhere and when I returned, my monitor has a black screen and the CPU switch button's light was flashing.

I have an HP computer and Asus motherboard.

Comment: Unplug the computer and wait a few seconds. Then plug it back in and turn it on. What happens? Do you see the BIOS/POST screen? Do you hear any beeps?

Answer (score 3):

Move the mouse/press the keyboard.  If that doesn't wake it up, press and release the power button on the computer.  It should wake it.

Comment: no i have done it but it doesnt work

Comment: i restarted the pc , shut it down but still when i open my computer
my moniters says moniter going to sleep and power switch light keeps flashing

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved — I just had to put the RAM into another RAM slot.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's what you need to do:

1. Unplug the machine, plug it back in and start a boot.
2. Check the cable, make sure its tight.
3. There's a small watch battery on the motherboard, start the system (no display is normal some times when the BIOS battery is out shut down the machine, put the battery back in.
4. This is probably the simplest one get a video card or call Asus they're usually pretty good with there customer service.